# What are examples of high volume apps running on Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

What are examples of high volume apps running atop of Google app engine?

Comment: You start with a statement, and then comes a question: "WTF?" Don't really know how to answer that.

Comment: Off-topic: the usability or otherwise of Google's App Engine website, and their marketing strategy whether they brag about their customers. Not programming issues.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with what we did with http://www.myappbox.com - it isn't super high volume, but it has gone from a few hundred to a few thousand visitors per day and we've never had any kind of scaling issues (besides getting charged a little bit for CPU usage)

Comment: Ah! A *WTF* in a question. No wait, it *is* the question. WTF!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) ([some projects](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/HubbubAtGoogle) that use it at Google)
- [jaiku](http://www.jaiku.com/)
- [wokhei](http://www.wokhei.com/)
- [snapabug](http://www.snapabug.com/)
- [giftag](http://www.giftag.com/)
- [overgrowth](http://www.wolfire.com/overgrowth)
- [webfilings](http://www.webfilings.com)
- [babelwith.me](http://www.babelwith.me/)
- etc

Answer (score 1):

[Google Moderator](https://www.google.com/moderator/) runs on App Engine, and ran whitehouse.gov's [Open for Questions](http://www.whitehouse.gov/openforquestions/) site for a while.

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPoke:

http://www.buddypoke.com/

http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/1/22/how-buddypoke-scales-on-facebook-using-google-app-engine.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zz-oSrWfj0

Answer (score 1):

Michael Brunton-Spall gave an entertaining and informative talk at this year's Europython conference on implementing the Guardian's realtime voting system for the UK's leadership debates from the last election.  This allowed users to vote up or down the three party leaders' performance over the space of each 90 minute debate.  This was initially implemented in 3 days on App Engine and successfully handled 1 million+ requests during each 90 minute debate.

The video is available [here](http://europythonvideos.blip.tv/file/3980962/).

He also did a talk on the Guardian Open Platform that Ron mentions in his answer.  Video [here](http://europythonvideos.blip.tv/file/3980959/).

Answer (score 0):

The Guardian newspaper in the UK, has developed "The Guardian Open Platform" as a means for 3rd parties to utilise their content.  Core part of this platform is the "MicroApps" framework they've developed with Google App Engine.

http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/microapps-from-guardian-and-google.html